# windows 2012 can't run cmd as admin from powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

Does anyone know if it's possible to modify the following:

```powershell
Start-Process "cmd.exe" "/c update.bat -config configfile.txt"
```

To run in an elevated cmd windows in server 2012. The batch script keeps failing because the cmd session isn't running in admin mode. It works fine on server 2008 as long as the user running the powershell script has admin access.

Have MS changed something in 2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```powershell
Start-Process "cmd.exe" "/c update.bat -config configfile.txt" -Verb RunAs
```

Comment: Cheers, I did try this but the batch file kept failing, I can only assume it's a bug with the script and server 2012.